# Change gradient background-color, slow animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css

I'm trying to change the background color on a section.

```
<section id="welcome" class="gradientBlue">
    <div class="mainTitle">
        <h1>Sdesigns</h1>
        <h2>Taking web design to the next level</h2>
        <div class="centerArrow">
            <i id="0" class="icon-caret-down arrow arrowDown"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The is how it currently looks:
[image: Th]

The Idea is when I press the arrow the background changes to another gradient color. I already set this class up. So It should slowly fade-in class "gradientGreen".

```
.gradientGreen{
    background-color:#39b54a;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#8dc63f), to(#205075));/* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */ 
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #8dc63f, #39b54a);/* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #8dc63f, #39b54a);/* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #8dc63f, #39b54a);/* IE 10 */
}
```

I already tried this and many more in Jquery but it always changes instant. I hope anyone can help me.

```
$('.arrowDown').click(function(e) {
    $("#welcome").addClass("gradientGreen");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Which font is that? It's cool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7awv/7/).

You can detach the background from the element by creating two separate `<div>`s with the gradients that are absolutely positioned beneath the target element. Then you can animate with the opacity to switch between these two gradients.

```html
<section id="welcome">
    <div class="mainTitle"><!-- your text --></div>
    <div id="back1" class="gradientBlue"></div>
    <div id="back2" class="gradientGreen"></div>
</section>
```

```css
#welcome {
    position: relative;
}
#back1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#back2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then change the opacity of the initial background.

```
$('.arrowDown').click(function (e) {
    $("#back1").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: How can you change the animation speed then?

Comment: @Sharpless Easy. Just add a duration argument in [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [the transition property](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/). It's all CSS3, no jquery needed !

**Edit :** my bad, as Antony said you can't apply transitions to background gradients.

Comment: +1 Because I would do same - js is overhead here - and you only need 1 class and 1 div - everything is just css3

Comment: @F.Müller This is a wrong answer. You cannot do transition over the gradient color.

Comment: @Antony - I just tested it, yes you can ! (might not work everywhere though)

Comment: @Orteil The article you linked explicitly says: "CSS3 gradients are not really properties, but are actually images created by the browser, they aren’t in that list of animatable properties."

Comment: @Antony hmm seems like you are right here - I am sorry I missed that one - edit you answer that I can redo voting.

Comment: @Antony - hot damn, my bad. You could apply the transition to the opacity to make your solution work without javascript, though !

Comment: @Orteil JavaScript is needed here because the change of color has to be initiated by a click, not hover or other pseudo properties of CSS.

Comment: @Antony oh... correct. I guess my, uh, work here is done ? (I'll leave now before I mess up even more haha)